# Express matching additional routes after one has already been found

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building a simple blog using Express 4.13.3 and Mongoose 4.2.4 and I'm encountering an issue where after a route has been matched, subsequent routes are also being matched which causes the app to crash.

The routes are mounted in the **app.js** file like so:

```
// Load blog routes.
var blogRoutes      = require('./app/routes/blog');

// Mount routes.
app.use(blogRoutes);
```

The contents of the **./app/routes/blog** file:

```
var express         = require('express');
var router          = express.Router();
var blogCtrl        = require('../controllers/blog');

// Home
router.get('/', blogCtrl.list);

// Static pages.
router.get('/about', blogCtrl.about);

// Blog posts.
router.get('/:postUrl', blogCtrl.detail);
```

The contents of the **../controllers/blog** file:

```
module.exports.list = function (req, res) {      
    Post.find(function (err, posts) {
        res.render('index', { 
            title: 'Home page',
            posts: posts
        });   
    });
}

module.exports.detail = function (req, res) {
    Post.findOne({ 'url': req.params.postUrl }, function (err, post) {
        res.render('post', { 
            title: post.title,
            post: post
        });
    });
}

module.exports.about = function (req, res) {
    res.render('about', { title: 'About' });
}
```

When I request either the root (/) or about (/about) pages, it renders correctly. However my issue is that the blog post route (/:postUrl) continues to be matched and because no url segment is passed, the app crashes when assigning 'post.title' to the 'title' key.

Admittedly I haven't added any middleware to catch errors, but I don't understand why after a route has been matched, subsequent routes are also trying to be loaded, even without a call to 'next()' to pass the request on.

I understand that '/about' would match the path '/:postUrl', but because the 'about' route is defined before, should it not simply match and end the request cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what it was. Essentially because of the way I defined the route for individual blog posts (**/:postUrl**), when a browser requested the favicon (which they can do automatically by looking in the root), my route was being matched.

This explains why the correct route would render up until the browser requested the favicon ('**/favicon.ico**') and then would crash.

To fix it I've done 2 things:

1. I've added the [serve-favicon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-favicon) middleware to my **app.js** file to handle requests for '**/favicon.ico**' and route the request to my '**public**' folder.
2. I've added error trapping to my blog detail route so that if a post can't be found, it forwards the error onto error-handling middleware to handle properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do that, you have to test in "/:postURl" if param is empty , if it is, render list.
Express can't know if it's / or /:postURl with null argument.

Express, match with regex all route, that's why /:postURl is fired

Comment: What's strange is that when I request any page (root, about or a single post), the page actually renders but once it's finished it then falls into the '/:postUrl' route which then throws the error. What I'm expecting is that because the correct route is matched initially, Express wouldn't then continue onto subsequent routes.

Comment: have you try res.send a json instead of res.render. Just for try